# I want the icon in bottom navigation to change color when I select it. Do I need to add a new icon or make an adjustment to the existing icon?

Tags: java, android-studio, icons, bottom-navigation-bar

I want the icon in the bottom navigation to change color when I select it or for the icon to appear thicker (like on Instagram or Twitter). Do I need to add a new icon or make adjustments to an existing icon?
(Android studio - java)

I am using android studio. Is there a setting or are 2 different icons added? For example, there are 2 home icons and when selected, does the other one appear?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.